# Wordpress - Call snippet on another snippet - How to manage bracket?

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets

I'm block into something silly.

I want to call another snippet into one snippet on Wordpress. This is the idea :

```
[ snippet01 param=[snippet02 param="awesomeParameter"]]
```

Badly, that is not working out of the box. I've trying with another bracket like "{", but this is also not working.

Do you have an answer ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what are the different cases you can have in the first "param" ?

Comment: There is the "true" code :  `[contact email_to=[xyz-ips snippet='UserMailOnProfile']]`

**contact** is a plug-in downloaded on the store which need the mail adress on a string (Ex: "something@true.com")

**xyz-ips** is another plug-in which allow me to create snippet. "UserMailOnProfile" is the name of the snippet which return the mail address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach for your case:
Instead of [ snippet01 param=[snippet02 param="awesomeParameter"]]
you can use this format:
[ snippet01 param="subsnippet-snippet02,param,awesomeParameter"]

Then easily parse and use it inside first shortcode:

```
function first_shortcode_function($args){
if (strpos($args["param"],"subsnippet-")===0){
$parts=explode("-",$args["param"]);
$snippe2_final=explode(",",$parts[1]);

do_shortcode("[".$snippe2_final[0]." ".$snippe2_final[1]."=".$snippe2_final[2]."]");
}
}
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks for the tips. Even if I would prefer something easier.

That's my return function :
`echo do_shortcode("[contact ".$option_01."]");`